# onFling method without required touch release for being called

Tags: android, gesture, android-gesture

I intended to write a small snake game in which the snake is controlled by swiping gestures.
I am currently using the onFling method to move the snake. The method looks like that:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    String direction = "";
    if(isPaused) {
        isPaused = false;
    }
    if(Math.pow((int)(e1.getX() - e2.getX()), 2) > Math.pow((int)(e1.getY() - e2.getY()), 2)) {
        if(e1.getX() > e2.getX()) {
            direction = "left";
            snake.onFling(direction);
        }else {
            direction = "right";
            snake.onFling(direction);
        }
    }else {
        if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) {
            direction = "up";
            snake.onFling(direction);
        }else {
            direction = "down";
            snake.onFling(direction);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

When the snake.onFling(direction) method gets called, the snake will change it's direction to the transferred String.

Now my problem is that the onFling method only gets called when one has made a gesture **and released the finger off the screen.**

I wanted to know whether there is an alternative method how to achieve the snake to change direction, without having to release the finger from the screen?